# Can't connect to remote MySql in Go

Tags: mysql, database, go, tcp, go-gorm

I need to connect to a remote MySql server using Go. I'm using following code to connect to MySql via gorm.

```
 type DBController struct {
    DB gorm.DB
}

func (dc *DBController) InitDB() {
    var err error

  host := v.GetString("db.mysql.host")
  port := v.GetString("db.mysql.port")

  user := v.GetString("db.mysql.user")
  pass := v.GetString("db.mysql.pass")

  db := v.GetString("db.mysql.db")

  //user:password@tcp(localhost:5555)/dbname
  conn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", user, pass, host, port, db)
  //conn := v.GetString($user+":"$pass+"@tcp("+$host+":"+$port+")/"+$db)
  log.Debug(conn)

    dc.DB, err = gorm.Open("mysql", conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when connect database, the error is '%v'", err)
    }
    dc.DB.LogMode(true)
}

func (dc *DBController) GetDB() gorm.DB {
  return dc.DB
}
```

When I run the Go server I'm getting following errors

```
No configuration file loaded - using defaults
:@tcp(:)/
Error when connect database, the error is 'dial tcp: unknown port tcp/'
exit status 1
```

How can fix this error?

Comment: Do you use 5555 as your MySQL port? I'm asking just in case, because the default one is 3306.

Comment: Is log.Debug(conn) printing the connection string :@tcp(:)/  ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing "v" is your config variable… Which contains no data, this is not a problem with Gorm, it's because dc.Open() is not receiving the config values.

If you try to run it with static data, it should work.